# SP1 instead RTM on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

After installing Service Pack 1 on SQL Server 2008 instance I expected @@version to be something like „Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1)…“. Despite my expectation @@version is still „Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM)…“ but with „(Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)“ at the end.
Can anyone tell me why this is so? Is this regular and expected?

I suspect this to cause the problem while connecting to that SQL server instance from another tool. The error text I got is „SQL Server Version: SQL Server 2008 RTM Enterprise Edition is not supported. Please install SQL Server 2008 SP1 or superior“.